# What is the JavaFX equivalent of a WPF StackPanel?

Tags: wpf, javafx

In WPF I used a `StackPanel` to display one item above another item (vertical orientation) or besides another item (horizontal orientation).

I spent almost an hour achieving the same with the JavaFX `StackPane` until I found out that the Java-version stacks items in Z-Order instead of X- or Y-Order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaFX `VBox` (vertical layout) and `HBox` (horizontal layout) are similar to `StackPanel`.

Comment: This [document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102) gives a run-down of the built-in layout panes.